# Find dual from primal optimization problem

Tags: optimization

I need to find the dual to the following optimization problem:

$\text{max} \{c x: A x \leq b, C y \geq d, x+y \geq 0\}$,

where $A$ and $C$ are matrices and $c$, $b$, $x$ and $y$ are vectors.

In order to so, I want to find a matrix $A'$ and a vector $b'$ to reduce this problem to the standard form

$\text{max} \{c x: A' x \leq b'\}$.

I know how to do this for problems containing additional constraints on the vector $x$, but I do not know how to combine the constraints $C y \geq d$ and $x+y \geq 0$ into one useful constraint on $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to combine your variables into a single vector $z = [x\ y]$, and write everything in terms of that. For example, you create the vector $c_x = [c\ 0]$ (i.e. it's just c padded out with zeros to multiply against the values of y) for your objective function, and you turn your three sets of constraints into a big single matrix multiplication where you build a block matrix out of A, C and a 1 vector with appropriate zero padding.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really did the trick for me! I will attach the solution for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach that just computes the formal dual:

The primal problem is $\sup_{x,y} \inf_{\alpha \ge 0, \beta \ge 0, \gamma \ge 0} c x + \alpha^T (b-Ax) + \beta^T (Cy-d) + \gamma^T x + \gamma^T y$.

The formal dual is $\inf_{\alpha \ge 0, \beta \ge 0, \gamma \ge 0} \sup_{x,y}  c x + \alpha^T (b-Ax) + \beta^T (Cy-d) + \gamma^T x + \gamma^T y$.

To simplify, note that we must have $c-\alpha^T A +\gamma^T = 0$ and  $\beta^T C + \gamma^T = 0$, otherwise the inside term is $\infty$.

Hence we have the formal dual
$\inf_{\alpha \ge 0, \beta \ge 0, c-\alpha^T A=\beta^TC, \beta^T C \ge 0}  \alpha^T b - \beta^T d$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the linear optimization problem

\begin{equation}\label{eq:original_problem}
\text{max}\{ c x: A x \leq b, C y \geq d, x + y \geq 0 \} = \text{max}\{ c x: A x \leq b, -C y \leq -d, -x - y \leq 0 \} .
\end{equation}

One may introduce the composite column vectors

\begin{align*}
z &:= \begin{bmatrix}
x \\ y
\end{bmatrix}, \\ 
b' &:= \begin{bmatrix}
b \\ -d \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}, 
\end{align*}

the composite row vector

\begin{equation*}
c' := \begin{bmatrix}
c & 0
\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation*}

and the composite matrix

\begin{equation*}
A' := \begin{bmatrix}
A & 0 \\ 0 & -C \\ -1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation*}

In this way, the linear optimization problem (\ref{eq:original_problem}) is written as

\begin{equation}\label{eq:matrix_form}
\text{max}\{ c' z: A' z \leq b' \}.
\end{equation}

Applying the strong duality theorem to (\ref{eq:matrix_form}), gives

\begin{equation}\label{eq:dual_matrix_form}
\text{max}\{ c' z: A' z \leq b' \} = \text{min}\{ u b': u A'= c', u \geq 0 \}.
\end{equation}

Here $u$ is the composite row vector with elements

\begin{equation*}
u = \begin{bmatrix}
\alpha & \beta & \gamma
\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation*}

where $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are row vectors.

By expanding the composite column vector $b'$, the composite row vectors $u$ and $c'$, and the composite matrix $A'$, (\ref{eq:dual_matrix_form}) is written as

\begin{equation}\label{eq:dual_algebra_form}
\text{min}\{ \alpha b - \beta d: \alpha A - \gamma = c, -\beta C - \gamma = 0, \alpha \geq 0, \beta \geq 0, \gamma \geq 0  \}.
\end{equation}

The objective function does not include the variable $\gamma$, and the constraint $\gamma \geq 0$ is incorporated into the other constraints in (\ref{eq:dual_algebra_form}), giving the final answer

\begin{equation}\label{eq:dual_final}
\text{min}\{ \alpha b - \beta d: \alpha A \geq c, \beta C \leq 0, \alpha A - c = -\beta C, \alpha \geq 0, \beta \geq 0 \}.
\end{equation}

Comment: Note that the constraints $\alpha A - \gamma =c, -\beta C - \gamma = 0$ are not equivalent to $\alpha A \ge c, \beta C \le 0$. The latter misses the fact that you must have $\alpha A -c= \beta C$.

Comment: Good point! I had not considered this.